# How to change the color of text programmatically with JSON

Tags: android, json, colors, textview

I have JSON file with object "status". Status has got 3 parameters: id, title, color.
My Model:

```
public int StatusId;
public String StatusTitle;
public String StatusColor;
```

My GetHelper:

```
JSONObject status = data.getJSONObject("status");
orderDetails.StatusId = status.getInt("id");
orderDetails.StatusTitle = status.getString("title");
orderDetails.StatusColor = status.getString("color");
```

When I get my string with color, I want put it. For this I do it:

```
statusTextView.setTextColor(mOrderDetailsInfo.StatusColor);
```

But It's not working.
I will be glad to any advice.

Comment: And what is `StatusColor`? A hex string? Try converting it to an integer?

Comment: StatusColor has this String #00E676

Comment: @ДенисКлимков try my answer

Comment: First of all, you should provide more details about what "not working" means. What happens when you compile and run your code? I also suggest that you familiarize yourself with the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/index.html). In this case, the [API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) provides details about how to use [`TextView.setColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor(int))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
statusTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(mOrderDetailsInfo.StatusColor));
```

Comment: @ДенисКлимков you are welcome if it help please tick mark and vote up. :)

Comment: I'm waiting for the timer allows :)